# How to save image into a main gallery?

Tags: android, image

I am trying to make a barcode generator with a library. The picture doesn't save into the main gallery. I don't want to save it into QRCode folder where I can find it only through File Manager.

I searched a lot but I cannot understand them.

I am a beginner that I would appreciate it if you explain it easily.

Many Thanks!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String savePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/QRCode/";
}
```

```
/**Barcode save*/
        findViewById(R.id.save_barcode).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    try {
                        boolean save = new QRGSaver().save(savePath, edtValue.getText().toString().trim(), bitmap, QRGContents.ImageType.IMAGE_JPEG);
                        String result = save ? "Image Saved" : "Image Not Saved";
                        Toast.makeText(activity, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        edtValue.setText(null);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to change a path?

Comment: @NadimAnsari   Yes, to the main gallery. For example, if I generate the QR code, I cannot see it on the gallery that I have to go into File Manager to check. It's uncomfortable.

Comment: Do you have folder of "QRCode" ? but you want to save it in Camera folder?am i right?

Comment: @NadimAnsari Yes, there is 'QRCode' folder but I want to save it in the Camera folder!

Comment: I have added my code. please look at that and if it really work then please accept it. thanks

Comment: @NadimAnsari Thank you so much. But I am really sorry that I am a super beginner that I don't know where to put this code. I only learned Kotlin last month, but I couldn't find a library in Kotlin. So I decided to use java although it's new to me. So I really don't know how to use it. Could you kindly explain where to put it? Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you share whole class ,So i know what is going on and where to set this?

Comment: @NadimAnsari  here is [link]https://github.com/woojuspace/qr-code-generate-practice/tree/main he

Comment: I have updated my answer . lemme know if it working or not?

Comment: @NadimAnsari (I thought I left a comment, but cannot find it). It worked perfectly!!! Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have folder of QRCode and But you want to save your image to Camera Folder then you have to make folder like this :

```
File dir = new File( Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
  Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "Camera");
```

**Updated as per Comment**

Change your path like below code :

```
private String savePath = 
  Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM) + "/Camera/"
```